# Position Relative of Child Div pushes other Parent Buttons

Tags: css, position, css-position

(I really didn't know how to title this. Anyway!)

I have a couple of HTML buttons stacked vertically, which I consider the parent level. When you hover over a button, I have a div (or the child level) appear to the right of the button. To force the div to the right, I use position:relative;...

```
position:relative;
top:-25px;
left:200px;
```

but the buttons underneath the hovered button get pushed down like the div existed below the button.

How can I show the child div without the buttons being pushed down, while keeping the tops of the parent button and child div lined up?

Here's a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Mbyu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a night of thinking about it, I figured I could use absolute positioning in conjunction with getting the position of the parent button via javascript:

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/8Mbyu/8/

```
.hiddenButtons { /*blue div*/
    display:none;
    background:#0af;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:210px;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
$('.parentButton').hover(function () {
    $('.hiddenButtons').hide();
    var childID = '#' + this.id + 'Child';
    var rect = document.getElementById(this.id).getBoundingClientRect();
    var top = rect.top;
    $(childID).css("top", top+1);
    $(childID).show();
});
```

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/1178486 !

I'm open to seeing cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you against using absolute positioning or is that ok? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Mbyu/2/) here.

```
.hiddenButtons { /*blue div*/
    display:none;
    background:#0af;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:9px;
    left:210px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not against it, but I'd like for the top of the parent button and the top of the child div to line up. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Your absolute comment gave me an idea and I found a solution.

Comment: @StoneRanger Really? great! What did you do in the end?